# Counting names using three columns - code

Tags: excel, vba

Using the following input data, I am trying to extract count for each name's (column D) type.

input example:

the current code, picks up count if column b is unique.

**desired output:**
RBS = 5, CA = 1, SG = 1,

I found this code and updated it to my requirements. however, I can not get it to output results, for the following condition:

**if column B (deal), column C (total) and column A (date) are unique (non-duplicate) then count the name's type as 1 otherwise if both three columns are duplicate, then only count as one.**
*(Desired Output)*

Hope the example above clarifies the logic a little clearer.

Any help on this issue would be very much appreciated.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for complex VBA here - a "simple" formula will do:

```
=SUM(--NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(C1,Input!$D:$D))))
```

(This assumes the name of the bank is stored in cell C1)

Please note that you need to enter this as an array formula, i.e. press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>!

Comment: Thank you for your response and help. The output is required to be shown in "sheet4" and the input table is in "sheet1", how can I update your formula for this requirement.  Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: You only need to replace `Input` with `Sheet1` :-)

Comment: Thank you that works great. I am very grateful for your solution and time.  Thank you so much peter.  Have a great day!